# Move a ball with accelerometer android

Tags: android, accelerometer

Hi I have write this code to move a simple ball with an ImageView and accelerometer but don't work. 
I have used ball.scrollTo(xa, ya) but this code doesn't work with a variable catching accelerometer

post my code:

Main.java

```
package com.crowley.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;


public class Main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
final String tag = "AccLogger";
SensorManager sensore=null;
TextView x=null;
TextView y=null;
TextView z=null;
TextView xat=null;
TextView yat=null;
String a;
String b;
private ImageView ball;

int xa=0;
int ya=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sensore = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    x= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x);
    y= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y);
    z= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z);
    xat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    yat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);
    ball.scrollTo(xa, ya);


    ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);


 }


  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
     Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
     float [] values = event.values;
     synchronized (this) {
             Log.d(tag, "onSensorChanged: " + sensor + ", x: " + 
                             values[0] + ", y: " + values[1] + ", z: " + values[2]);
     if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER ) {
         x.setText("x"+ values[0]);
         y.setText("y"+ values[1]);
         z.setText("z"+ values[2]);

         xa=(int)values[0];// this part of code is only test to see int x and y on Activity
         ya=(int)values[1];

         a=Integer.toString(xa);
         b=Integer.toString(ya);

         xat.setText(a);
         yat.setText(b);

         //x.setText("x"+ SensorManager.DATA_X);
         //y.setText("y"+ SensorManager.DATA_Y);
         //z.setText("z"+ SensorManager.DATA_Z);
     }
     }
  }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    Log.d(tag,"onAccuracyChanged: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);
 }

  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Sensor Accel = sensore.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
   // register this class as a listener for the orientation and accelerometer sensors
    sensore.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, Accel,        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/y"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/x"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/z"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/y"
    android:text="" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ball"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ball" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="66dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work?  So the sun goes dark when run your code?  Do you want to tell us any more?  "It doesn't work" is perhaps the most useless thing you can say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change the ball's position when the sensor changes.

I haven't tested it but you should do something like that:

at the end of `onSensorChanged()` add `ball.scrollBy(xa, ya);` or something similar.

You make a call to `ball.scrollTo(x,y);` in your `onCreate()`, but once your sensor starts reporting, you don't move the ball at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong.
You are not moving your ImageView. You only set its coordinates in the onCreate() method. You should set it all the time - in the onSensorChanged method.

Second, you should NOT use scrollTo, but `offsetLeftAndRight(int offset)` & `offsetTopAndBottom(int offset)` and call ball.`invalide()` at the end of the `onSensorChanged` method.